# Backbonejs: updating subviews and views when needed upon route navigation

Tags: view, backbone.js, routes

we have a small questionaire application,
and 1 of the main sections is the questionaire itself.

it has a big view for some general templating, introduction and title etc
and it has subviews per question (with next and previous buttons)

we decided to use routing, because from several places one can jump to a specific question
so we use /ivr/4   to show question 4,  and  /ivr/overview  showing the final overview.

so in a way you go from  /ivr/1 to /ivr/2 ... to /ivr/overview

now, if one comes from /ivr/1 and arrives on /ivr/2
the big view is there, and it should only update the question to the right question

but when you arrive from /home  to /ivr/2
the big view is not loaded, so one should first open the questionaire and then load question 2

currently i have it always rerendering the big view
which works, but is lots of overhead and i would like to refactor this to a better way.

can anyone give me some guidance as to how i would structure routeActions and or views
to only update the big parentview when it actually needs to, and do the question view only, if the parent view is already there.

do i need events? 
or would i go with partial routes?

any tip is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both of your proposed solutions sound workable. If you go with events, I'd recommend using the [event aggregator pattern](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/) to facilitate communication between your views. This seems like the simpler option to me.

The other solution, partial routes, might be more involved. Check out the [Backbone.Marionette](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/16/composite-javascript-applications-with-backbone-and-backbone-marionette/) plugin, which was designed to help manage complex view manipulation.

Comment: what i especially want is that the routing still works, like if a user goes between questions or pages, the back button must throw them to the previous question. so event's make that more tricky if you ask me. unless with every event we trigger a history state?
that's why i was thinking about the routing first.

Comment: i went for the event way. partial routes gave me a headache, and since we already had the event system in place it worked without much trouble